# reading REST POST response node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, https, http-post

I am able to test a post call in rest client which shows headers as:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 49
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Fri, 14 Apr 2017 21:05:42 GMT
```

my code to invoke the post is as follows:

```
var https = require('https');
... var jsonObject = JSON.stringify({
            "Name" : optyName
        });

        // prepare the header
        var postheaders = {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json',
            'authorization' : 'Basic am9obi5kdW5iYXI6dnBoODk1ODM=',
            gzip: true
        };

        // the post options
        var optionspost = {
            host : 'myhost',
            port : 443,
            path : '/salesApi/resources/11.1.11/opportunities?fields=OptyId&onlyData=true',
            method : 'POST',
            headers : postheaders,
        };

        // do the POST call
        var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(error,response,body) {
             console.log('the decoded data is: ' + body)
         });

  reqPost.write(jsonObject);
        reqPost.end();
}
```

However i get the printed stuff:

```
the decoded data is: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

var http = require("http"),
    zlib = require("zlib");

function getGzipped(url, callback) {
    // buffer to store the streamed decompression
    var buffer = [];

```
http.get(url, function(res) {
    // pipe the response into the gunzip to decompress
    var gunzip = zlib.createGunzip();            
    res.pipe(gunzip);

    gunzip.on('data', function(data) {
        // decompression chunk ready, add it to the buffer
        buffer.push(data.toString())

    }).on("end", function() {
        // response and decompression complete, join the buffer and return
        callback(null, buffer.join("")); 

    }).on("error", function(e) {
        callback(e);
    })
}).on('error', function(e) {
    callback(e)
});
```

}

getGzipped(url, function(err, data) {
   console.log(data);
});

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the response body in your code, not the response headers.

Try this code in order to see the headers:

```
var reqPost = https.request(optionspost, function(error,response,body) {
    console.log('response headers: ' + response.getHeaders())
});
```

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_getheaders